# Trying to create a LocalDate in Java with a given String

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, jodatime

I have this string:

```
"1991-02-01T02:00:00.000Z"
```

And I need to create a localDate from it so I'm making this:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").parseLocalDate("1991-02-01T02:00:00.000Z");
```

But its returning me an "IllegalArgumentException".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is `yyyy-MM-dd` related to the `String`?

Comment: According to the docs, the exception is thrown when the text to parse is invalid: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseLocalDate(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the [JavaDocs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) to familiarize yourself with the required format specifiers.

With a value of `1991-02-01T02:00:00.000Z`, you need to include `yyyy-MM-dd` and `HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`, as the `String` contains both elements, even if you're only interested in the "date" part.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").
                                   parseLocalDate("1991-02-01T02:00:00.000Z")
```